# SQL Server Reporting Services - permission always denied

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Right, when I logged in using a domain account for my database on the SQL Server Reporting Services, it worked absolutely fine, however on another machine I have entered the wrong password by accident and now it will not let me log in again. I've tried clearing the internet cache, stored passwords etc... and still no luck. So currently I am locked out of the report server on a machine.

Is there a way to make it forget so I can login from scratch?

Cheers for any help

Error:

> The permissions granted for user 'domain\username' are insufficient
>   for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

I know they are not insufficient as I use my account on another machine no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different browser first. If that doesn't work, try clearing the stored passwords off your system.
You can refer [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-do-i-clear-cached-credentials-from-my-windows-profile).

Answer (score 0):

the login and password works, that's not the issue. please open internet explorer as an administrator (right-click, run as administrator), open  `http://localhost/Reports/` and check under "site settings" on the top right corner that the permissions are set correctly.